# I cannot understand the benefit of using interface over type alias

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

In my understanding, I believed that

Interface = useful when I want to use the concept of "inheritance"  because type alias cannot use the concept of inheritance.

```
interface a {
  name:string;
}

interface b {
  age: number;
}

interface c extends a,b {
}

const d:c ={
  name:'Anderson',
  age:28
}
```

type alias = it is useful when I want to use the concept of things like union.

Yet as type alias cannot use "Inheritance", in general, I can use interface and "only when" I have to use union type, it is beneficial for me to adopt "type alias".

However, after I learnt the concept of "Intersection types" I was confused because it seemed acting like "inheritance"

```
type a = {
  name:string;
}

type b = {
  age : number;
}

type c = a&b;

const results:c ={
  name:"Anderson",
  age:28
}
```

What I want to know is why I have to adhere to using interface even though I can imitate like "inheritance" things by type alias.

is there any wrong point in my understanding?

Comment: https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/interface-vs-type-alias-in-typescript-2-7-2a8f1777af4c

Comment: thank a lot. After all, I understood that ,except for the case I want to use the concept of declaration merging, it is better for me to use type alias because it allows me to use more flexible things.

Comment: Depends on your needs of course :)